# Sending messages 15 times a 24-hour day hourly

Tags: php, algorithm, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a CRON job which starts every hour and sends messages. If it starts every hour, it sends messages 24 times a day. A user may set a different amount of times a CRON job may start - if he chooses 12 times, cron jobs will work every odd (or even) hour in the following pattern:

- 10101010...etc

where 1 is the hour job worked and 0 is an idle hour. The problem is I dont know how to make a program workout such a pattern for all other amount of times automatically, say for 15 or 17 or somethins else. For such user inputs the pattern would be:

- 110110110...etc

with last hours broken (it will be something like 111 or 100). I tried to divide 15 by 24, add 1, then compare it with the amount of hours since last sending (if 1<1.5 then don`t send, 2>1.5 then send) but I end up with 101010 pattern everytime. And unfortunately I cannot run CRON every minute, it starts only on hourly basis. Thank you.

Comment: *A user may set a different amount of times a CRON job may start*  - allow the user to select only certain numbers - 12, 6, 4, 3.2, 1. Others are  mischief

Comment: The problem is that user is allowed to select any whole integer from 1 to 24 (1,2,3,4,5,6...22,23,24). Numbers like 2.5, 3.2364 etc. are not allowed

Comment: That is what splash is syaing, do not allow that. Be the boss and say no.

Comment: What a reason to set, for example, 5 but not 6 or 4?  Why he want  receive messages every 4.8 of hour?

Comment: it sounds like you're actually asking how to divide  24 by 17 evenly, but that couldn't be, because that would be a ridiculous question..

Comment: The problem is how to start a CRON job 15 times evenly during 24 hours assuming that CRON is started hourly. I know that 15 cannot be divided by 24 without a remaining part so we may use the last hour for it. If user chooses 15, we should start CRON 15 times a day but do it as evenly as possible on hourly basis

Comment: @PootieTang kind off. I think the issue is how to evenly spread the 7 non run times on the 24 hours.

Comment: Can't you instead create a "pick your times" form for the user instead. Say 24 checkboxes and the checks the ones he/she wants. And then it will be easy to build the string from that. It will save you a big problem. You can have som pre defined buttons as "every other hour", "8-20" and so on.

Comment: do as andreas suggested. that makes waaaay more sense than trying to hack the laws of math and nature.

Comment: @PootieTang haha! `hack the laws of math and nature.` that is going to make me grin at night

Comment: 24 checkboxes is a better-than-nothing variant, but I am trying to find something more user-friendly. Unfortunately right now we have only 1 input field where only numbers from 1 to 24 are allowed((

Comment: So change it? I'm not sure it's not user friendly. IF, and I mean **IF** I ever want a page to send me a message more than once a day I would want to say when. But I find it strange that a page would send up to 24 messages to me a day

Comment: Its a corporate news site. The users want to receive news on some basis they choose and some of them opted for 24-hour feature.

Comment: Also the `24 checkboxes` is the worst case in my opinion. You could have three radiobuttons sayin "every hour" "every other hour" "every three hours", and then a start and end time. And if that is not detailed enough for the user you could have the 24 checkboxes

Comment: If it's news then I would not want it in the middle of the night. Another reason why the user should be able to choose him/herself

Comment: If the user chooses 16 times a day then only 2/3 of the messages (roughly) will be sent when he/she is awake. That does not make any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you're trying to do, the more frequently the cron job runs, the more accurate your times will be. If it HAS to be every hour, then anything the user selects between 17 and 24 will execute every hour. Therefore it really wouldn't make sense to even provide all those options. If you HAVE to let the user choose a number and execute it evenly throughout the day, you will have to run the cron job more frequently than once er hour.

This example assumes you run the cron job once per minute, ie:

`*/1   *    *    *    *     <your command>`

```
// How many times per day, get from DB
$userInput = 17;

$SecondsPerDay = 60 * 60 * 24;

$Frequency = (int) ($SecondsPerDay / $userInput) -1;

$midnight = strtotime('today midnight');

// Get an array of times to execute
$executeTimes = array();
for($time=$midnight; $time<=($midnight+$SecondsPerDay); $time+=$Frequency)
    $executeTimes[] = date("g:i a", $time);

$currentTime = date("g:i a");
$execute = in_array($currentTime, $executeTimes);

if(!$execute) exit;

// Cron job codes here
```

Here is an exmaple: https://3v4l.org/0PCXh

note: I think ther's an off-by-one error but you should get the gist from this..

Comment: Thats a good idea, but how to make a $runTimes string automatically based only on the number a user inputs into textfield?

Comment: Nicely done! +1. But as I wrote in the comments above it does not make any sense to get news updates when you are asleep.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all you want is to make a pattern of 0's and 1's where the user picks how often a 1 should appear and they be evenly spaced...

You want 24 total digits. Assume that `$n` is the number of hours between events. So, `$n=1` means every 1 hour. Then, just use a 1 whenever the hour is evenly divisible by the number of hours between events...

```
$pattern = '';
for($h=1; $h<=24; $h++)
  $pattern.= ($h%$n==0) 1 : 0;
```

This will give you 111111111111111111111111 if $n=1 (every hour). It will be 0101010101... if $n=2. It will be 001001001001 if $n=3, etc...

Comment: But how do you make 17 "1"s?

Comment: @Andreas So $n is number of times in a 24 hour period, not number of hours between events? That is an entirely different problem.

Comment: Andreas is  right, we should start CRON 17 times in 24-hour day on hourly basis, but do this as evenly as possible. As far as I understand now the pattern will be broken in last hour, it will be 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 111 for a 17-times CRON start (note 3 last ones)